# SELECT MAX de un campo VARCHAR

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente inquitud.
Actualmente tengo un campo que debe ser varchar que puede o no tener un caracter (letra) seguido de un numero.
Ejemplo:

```
----------
id | campo
----------
1    G1
2    G2
..........
8    T8
9    T9
..........
16   1
17   2
18   3
```

Lo que necesito es sacar el MAX de cada 'campo' independiente que tenga caracter (letra o no).
Actualmente estoy usando:

```
SELECT

MAX(CAST(campo as SIGNED)) AS nom_campo

FROM
mi_tabla

WHERE id_cliente = 1
```

Haciendo eso, funciona bien, pero solo en los registros que NO tienen un caracter al comienzo (campo).

Alguna idea de como puedo hacer para que independiente de que si tenga letra o no, pueda seleccionar el MAX de cada campo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, tienes dos patrones: (a) un número, (b) una letra más un número. Lo que deberías hacer es dividir este campo en dos, una parte el "grupo" y otra para el número. Lo que hay que considerar aparte son los números sin letras, que asignaremos igual a un grupo, esto le vemos chequeando si el primer caracter de `campo` es un numérico mediante `CAMPO REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAMPO REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(CAMPO, 1, 1) END as grupo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CAMPO REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN CAMPO ELSE SUBSTRING(CAMPO, 2 ) END) as id
       FROM (SELECT 'G1' as CAMPO UNION
             SELECT 'G2' UNION
             SELECT 'T8' UNION
             SELECT 'T9' UNION
             SELECT '1' UNION
             SELECT '2' UNION
             SELECT '3'
        ) T
        GROUP BY CASE WHEN CAMPO REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(CAMPO, 1, 1) END
```

Por supuesto habrá que agrupar por el "grupo".

```
| grupo | id |
|-------|----|
|       |  3 |
|     G |  2 |
|     T |  9 |
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me oriento mucho tu informacion. Estaba haciendo algo parecido pero sin la agrupacion. Agregue eso y funciono como necesitaba. muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda. saludos.